# UFW not allowing Transmission to transfer

Tags: transmission, ufw

I have set the rules in `ufw` for Transmission but when I try to use it it will not transfer and it also says the port is closed when checked under preferences.

If I turn the UFW firewall off it still says that the port is closed but it transfers fine. I then can turn the UFW back on and it continues to work. I have tried setting up port forwarding in my router (Asus rtn12 using DD-WRT 17990) but that has no effect on the closed port message or transferring.

Is there a specific port that should be opened in UFW to allow the transfers or am I just missing something?

I'm a linux nube so please explain any answers a little more thoroughly than normal. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add a rule using the `gufw` (the UFW GUI) program to allow the port that's set in Transmission. Actually, gufw has a handy preset for Transmission.

Comment: Where can I find that preset on Ubuntu 16.04's gufw?

Comment: Just enable UFW from gufw and under rules, click the + button. This brings you to the Preconfigured tab on the Add a Firewall Rule dialog. On this tab, click the Application drop-down and Transmission is available in the list of applications if it's installed (which is should be by default).

Answer (score 0):

you will need to enable UPnP in your router ... then using the default incoming/deny outgoing/allow settings for Gufw (reboot if enabled for 1st time), open preferences and select Listening Report and Show notifications. select add rule / Simple Tab / Allow in TCP and port selected in Torrent client / do the same add rule and port for UDP

when you have set these you should see your port in RED in Listening Report